# Put values in the same column

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a problem when I try to put values in a column, 
this is my code:

```
        scelta.put(Codice.DATI_NOME_DIETA, "Scarsdale");
        scelta.put(Codice.DATI_NOME_DIETA, "Dieta Atkins");
        scelta.put(Codice.DATI_NOME_DIETA, "Dieta dissociata");
        scelta.put(Codice.DATI_NOME_DIETA, "Weight Watchers");
        scelta.put(Codice.DATI_NOME_DIETA, "Dieta Zona");
        scelta.put(Codice.DATI_NOME_DIETA, "La dieta Dukan");
        scelta.put(Codice.DATI_NOME_DIETA, "Cronodieta");

        db.insert(Codice.TABLE_SCELTA, null, scelta);
```

But when I print the table I see only the last value "Cronodieta" and not all the values.

Comment: using `put()` and same `key`, you are replacing the last set value. Hence, only last value is printed.

Comment: You are only inserting the last value. You must perform a `db.insert()` for each value.

Comment: @IndexOutOfBounds Yes I know, but how I can put all the values without replacing ?

Comment: Execute as many inserts as many values you have.

Comment: You can only insert a single row with an insert.

Comment: Multiple inserts needed here. Tying them in a single transaction will be much more efficient.

Comment: And more secure, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How would I do it:

```
String[] values =
    "Scarsdale,Dieta Atkins,Dieta dissociata,Weight Watchers,Dieta Zona,La dieta Dukan,Cronodieta".split(",");

for(String value : values)
{
    scelta.put(Codice.DATI_NOME_DIETA, value);
    db.insert(Codice.TABLE_SCELTA, null, scelta);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Slaiv206

See you are setting up different value on a same key name, so each time the value you written will be Overwritten. So use like below

```
String[] DATI_NOMES = {"Scarsdale","Dieta Atkins","Dieta dissociata",...,"Cronodieta"}

for(int i=0; i < DATI_NOMES.length;i++){

 scelta.put(Codice.DATI_NOME_DIETA, DATI_NOMES[i]);
 db.insert(Codice.TABLE_SCELTA, null, scelta);

}
```

Comment: Or: `for(String value : DATI_NOMES){scelta.put(Codice.DATI_NOME_DIETA, value);`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a loop in your activity and then calls the database insert function to add values :

```
String[] s = {"a", "b",....};
for(int i=0; i<s.length;i++){
db.insert(s[i]);
}
```

Try it.